# sum up property values when id matches and return the result using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I am trying to achieve a pretty complex iteration but havent been successful so far using reduce. Here is a small example of it

The input is as follows

```
let input = {
    "data": [
        {
            "state": "CA",
            "tests": 12,
            "city": [ "Mountain View"],
            "metadata": { "id": 15 },
        },
        {
            "state": "TX",
            "tests": 10,
            "city": [ "Austin" ],
            "metadata": { "id": 15 },
        },
        {
            "state": "AZ",
            "tests": 5,
            "city": [ "Flagstaff" ],
            "metadata": { "id": 10 },
        },
    ],
}
```

As you can clearly see, the id is repeated twice in 2 objects. i want to concatenate these two objects into one when id is same. so if there are 3 objects with same id, i want to concatenate 3 objects as one. Apart from this, i also want to concatenate the state an city property when the id is matched. and the `tests` should add up too when the id is matched.

So my final output should look like this

```
let result = {
    "data": [
        {
            "state": ["CA", "TX"],
            "tests": 22,
            "city": ["Mountain View", "Austin"],
            "metadata": { "id": 15 },
        },
        {
            "state": "AZ",
            "tests": 5,
            "city": [ "Flagstaff" ],
            "metadata": { "id": 10 },
        },
    ],
}
```

can someone please let me know how to precisely achieve this. Here is how i have tried using reduce and i have reached half way. the only thing i am unable to get is how do i sum up `tests` property when id is matched and get the `tests` total to be 22 in this case.

```
let total_tests = 0;
let res = [{
  data: Object.values(input[0].data.reduce((acc, {state, city, metadata, tests, category
  }) => {
    const id = metadata ? .id;

    if (!acc[id]) {
      acc[id] = {
        id,
        state: [],
        city: [],
        metadata,
        tests,
        category
      }
    }
    acc[id].state.push(state)
    acc[id].city.push(...city)
    debugger
    acc[id].tests = total_tests + acc[id].tests;
    return acc
  }, {}))
}]
```

Comment: Don't mix arrays and strings in the same property. `state: 'AZ'` should be `state: ['AZ']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialise the object with

```
tests: 0
```

and add the actual value to the object/property with the same `id`:

```
acc[id].tests += tests;
```

```js
const
    input = { data: [{ state: "CA", tests: 12, city: ["Mountain View"], metadata: { id: 15 } }, { state: "TX", tests: 10, city: ["Austin"], metadata: { id: 15 } }, { state: "AZ", tests: 5, city: ["Flagstaff"], metadata: { id: 10 } }] },
    result = [{
        data: Object.values(input.data.reduce((acc, { state, city, metadata, tests }) => {
            const id = metadata?.id;
            acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, state: [], city: [], metadata, tests: 0 };
            acc[id].state.push(state);
            acc[id].city.push(...city);
            acc[id].tests += tests;
            return acc;
        }, {}))
    }];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it is adding up for all the objects. whereas i want to add for only those objects which has same `id`

Comment: it works as expected. one with `5` and the other with `22`.

Comment: is there any other way to implement this ? unfortunately this line of code below results in error `acc[id] ??= { id, state: [], city: [], metadata, tests: 0 }` what does ??= do in this case ? probably some new way of implementation but my current react loader doesnot recognize this code

Comment: it was a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), now replaced with an assignment with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR). please see edit.

Comment: this works and is a clean implementation. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start with `reduce` function to iterate thru `input.data`.

for each object get the `id`.

initialize `state` and `city` properties as `Set objects` to ensure uniqueness.

if the id is already present in the accumulator, then update its properties.

after the reduction is complete, convert each state and city set back to an array using the spread operator `([...set])`.

```js
let input = {
  "data": [{
      "state": "CA",
      "tests": 12,
      "city": ["Mountain View"],
      "metadata": {
        "id": 15
      },
    },
    {
      "state": "TX",
      "tests": 10,
      "city": ["Austin"],
      "metadata": {
        "id": 15
      },
    },
    {
      "state": "AZ",
      "tests": 5,
      "city": ["Flagstaff"],
      "metadata": {
        "id": 10
      },
    },
  ],
};

let result = Object.values(input.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let id = curr.metadata.id;
  if (!acc[id]) {
    acc[id] = { ...curr
    };
    acc[id].state = new Set([curr.state]);
    acc[id].city = new Set([...curr.city]);
  } else {
    acc[id].state.add(curr.state);
    acc[id].tests += curr.tests;
    curr.city.forEach(city => acc[id].city.add(city));
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

result.forEach(obj => {
  obj.state = [...obj.state];
  obj.city = [...obj.city];
});

result = {
  "data": result
};

console.log(result);
```